# Why doesn't strace -f work on GNOME Terminal?

Tags: gnome-terminal, strace

I tried running the command

```
strace -f gnome-terminal --wait |& grep write
```

and then in the terminal window that opened, I typed `ls` and pressed enter.

I expected to see `write` syscalls corresponding to the `l`, `s`, `\n` characters getting sent to the Bash child process running inside the terminal as well `write` syscalls when the `ls` child-child process wrote its output, but instead I didn't see any syscalls happening when I ran `ls`.

I do see these `write` syscalls when I run

```
strace -f xterm |& grep write
```

Why does `strace -f` fail to follow the child processes of `gnome-terminal`?

Comment: Not an answer to your question but a workaround for attaching the process. Since gnome terminal seems to work different you can attach the shell instead of the terminal. When gnome terminal is opened you should use `echo $$` to get the pid of the current shell and attach this one by using: `sudo strace -fp thepid` (you might need to use sudo , otherwise you'll get operation not permitted)

Comment: The actual `gnome-terminal-server` that's doing the terminal emulation isn't a descendant of the `gnome-terminal` command you launch. `gnome-terminal` starts up `gnome-terminal-server` via some systemd / dbus or similar magic (which I'm not familiar with). You can figure out `gnome-terminal-server`'s PID and attach to it via `strace -p PID`. Note that if you have multiple gnome-terminal tabs or windows, this will trace all of them.

Comment: @egmont if you write up your comment as an answer I would accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

The actual `gnome-terminal-server` that's doing the terminal emulation isn't a descendant of the `gnome-terminal` command you launch. `gnome-terminal` starts up `gnome-terminal-server` via some `systemd` / `dbus` or similar magic (which I'm not familiar with), i.e. asks an already running service to launch the terminal.

You can figure out `gnome-terminal-server`'s PID and attach to it using `strace -p PID`. Note that if you have multiple `gnome-terminal` tabs or windows, this will trace all of them.